# iOS correct dateFormat for "Optional(1),Optional(19),Optional(2017)"

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

```
let dateStr1 = "1:19:2017" // Type one
let dateStr2 = "1,19,2017" // Type two
let dateStr3 = "(1)(19)(2017)" // Type three
let dateStr4 = "Optional(1),Optional(19),Optional(2017)"

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "mm:dd:yyyy"
let date1 = dateFormatter.date(from: dateStr1)
// ouput: Jan 19, 2017, 12:01 AM

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "mm,dd,yyyy"
let date2 = dateFormatter.date(from: dateStr2)
// ouput: Jan 19, 2017, 12:01 AM

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "(mm)(dd)(yyyy)"
let date3 = dateFormatter.date(from: dateStr3)
// ouput: Jan 19, 2017, 12:01 AM

dateFormatter.dateFormat = ? // what would be correct formatted string
let date4 = dateFormatter.date(from: dateStr4)
// ouput: nil
```

Now my question is that what would be the correct date format for `dateStr4`. I know I can do this by removing `Optional` substring from that string. But I don't want to do that. I just want to know what should be the correct formatted string?

Comment: It's better to prevent string with `Optional(n)` being created than do this parsing voodoo, [XY-Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: unwrap the optionals explicitly then parse the date (1-19-2017) via `DateFormatter` using e.g. `d-MM-yyyy`, or something.

Comment: Don't try to parse dateStr4. Unwrap the optionals.

Comment: Actually it comes from backend. So I could not prevent Optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct dateFormat is:

```
dateFormater.dateFormat = "'Optional'(mm),'Optional'(dd),'Optional'(yyyy)"
```

Output: `2017-01-18 18:01:00 +0000`

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to display the contents of optionals. Post your code and we can help you fix it.

In general, you'd use code like this:

```
var dateString: String 
if 
  let month = month,
  let day = day, 
  let year = year {
    dateString = "\(day) Month \(month), \(year)"
  }
  else { 
    dateString = "One of your components is nil"
  }
```

That `if let` syntax is called "optional binding".

Better still would be to use a `DateFormatter` to convert your date to a string automatically. `DateFormatter` objects handle conversion to different country's date formats automatically, and that can be **very** complex.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly finds that the date substrings are optionals, What u can do is while concatenating the date element, make sure that the variables are unwrapped.

**use `if let {}` or `!` to unwrap optional variables .**